# Is my implementation of stack pop leaking memory?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am doing this for learning purpose. From what I have learnt, every `new` needs to have corresponding `delete`. Is my `pop()` definition causing memory leak? It pops out `head`, but I don't know how to delete just the `head`.

From my understanding, it may not have memory leak, but I am not sure (Valgrind didn't find anything):

1. save the `head` pointer in `temp` pointer.
2. point `head` to `head->next`.
3. return the `data` in `temp`.
4. the memory free automatically at the end of `}` block.

But from my understanding, what I really really want to do is to call `delete head`. Because `head` is in the heap and it needs to be deleted when popped. But I am also thinking that since its a recursive data structure, if I call `delete head`, I will delete everything recursively like I defined it in `~Node()`, right? If I want to save `head` in a `temp` point like this `Node* temp = head`, won't I just make a copy? So I tried using `Node*temp = std::move(head); head = std::move(temp->next); delete temp;`, then an error pops up `free(): double free detected in tcache 2`, what does that mean? At this point, I don't know how to proceed. I have searched everywhere and can't find a solution. Tried this, with no success:

1. save the `head` pointer in `temp` pointer.
2. save the `data` from `temp->data`.
3. point `head` to `head->next`.
4. set `temp->next` to `nullptr`?

   - cause `temp` holds recursive nodes
   - how do I extract just the `head` without those nodes in `next`?
5. `delete temp` to delete the original `head`?
6. return the `data`.

I know how to implement this using `unique_ptr`, which solves all my problems and makes me worry free. But I need to know how to do this manually.

```
template<typename Data>
class ListStack {
public:
    ListStack(): head{nullptr} {}

    ~ListStack();

    [[nodiscard]] bool isEmpty() const;

    void push(Data const &data);

    Data pop();

private:
    struct Node {
        Data data;
        Node* next;

        explicit Node(Data const &data, Node* next=nullptr) : data{data}, next{next} {}

        ~Node() { delete next; }
    };

    Node* head;
};

template<typename Data>
bool ListStack<Data>::isEmpty() const {
    return head == nullptr;
}

template<typename Data>
void ListStack<Data>::push(Data const &data) {
    head = new Node(data, head);
}

template<typename Data>
Data ListStack<Data>::pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("ListStack underflow");
    }
    Node* temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    return temp->data;
}

template<typename Data>
ListStack<Data>::~ListStack() { delete head; }
```

Another try with last resort using recursive delete, why error `free(): invalid pointer`?

```
template<typename Data>
Data ListStack<Data>::pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("ListStack underflow");
    }
    Node* temp = new Node(head->next->data, head->next->next);
    Data data = head->data;
    delete head;
    head = temp;
    return data;
}
```

Working example using `unique_ptr`, please tell me if there is anything wrong:

```
template<typename Data>
Data ListStack<Data>::pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("ListStack underflow");
    }
    Data data = head.get()->data;

    // ~Node() and ~ListStack() are not implemented, using default.
    // head and next are std::unique_ptr<Node>
    head = std::move(head.get()->next);
    // here the original head has no one owns it, so it gets freed automatically.
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Removing the destructor will leak memory. The memory allocation here is someone awkward. This is why similar C++ library containers do not implement `pop()` this way. Instead, they implement `front()`, separately, and `pop()` does not return anything, and only removes the front value from the container.

Comment: Wow, didn't think it would get this complicated in C++. With garbage collected language, it would be a trivial to implement a stack. I guess this is when smart_ptr (like a form of garbage collecting) comes in, to make things easier.

Comment: C++ is complicated. There's no denying it. But from that complication comes control and from that control the ability to finely tune the program for performance. With great power comes great responsibility.

Comment: Exactly, and it's my favorite language. It let me get to know how things actually works. Instead of gluing APIs together. I love thinking about data structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by drawing a graph.

Class in C++ is just an array. For example, in my implementation of `Node`, if `Data` is `int`, and `next` is a pointer, which is an `int` too. 64bit int is 8bytes, which means every filled `head` is 16byte (I printed `sizeof(head)`, which is `16`, which proved this point).

```
head
-----------
|Data|next| =>
-----------
-----------
|Data|next| =>
-----------
-----------
|Data|NULL|
-----------
tail
```

What I want the result to be. And delete the head array:

```
original head, set next to nullptr, can be deleted safely
-----------
|Data|NULL|
-----------

temp, hold the new head
-----------
|Data|next| =>
-----------
-----------
|Data|NULL|
-----------
tail
```

This is the code:

```
template<typename Data>
Data ListStack<Data>::pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("ListStack underflow");
    }
    // copy the next pointer to a local varialbe temp pointer
    Node* temp = head->next;
    Data data = head->data;

    // this step separated head from the rest
    head->next = nullptr;

    // to be popped head gets deleted, conform to one new one delete principle
    delete head;

    // copy temp pointer to head
    head = temp;
    return data;

    // all locally allocated memory get freed here
}
```